# Prism and MVVM, property and button binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, prism

I am new to prism but has some experience with Caliburn Micro.

I read the prism documentation and understand how prism would bind ViewModel to view, but can not find documentation on how it would bind XAML objects (linked a text box) to the associated properties in ViewModel.

I Caliburn Micro, I can define an text box in the view like this:

```
  <Text x:name="MyInput"/>
```

and have a property in ViewModel with the name of "MyInput" and Caliburn micro will automatically bind them to each other, also if I have a button called "MyButton" in View, its click is automatically bound to a function in my ViewModel called MyButton".

When I tried this in Priem, It did not work. Is this type of binding supported in Prism?

If yes, where can I find documentation?

I am using Prism in a Xamarin form project.

Comment: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html#views

Comment: @Jason Thanks, The page says that the binding would be done automatically based on the name, but in the view, the binding is done explicitly " <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />" this is the same for button click "<Button Text="Speak" Command="{Binding SpeakCommand}"/>". So I am not sure how the auto wiring is works here?

Comment: I believe the auto wiring just ties the page to the VM - it does not automatically tie views to properties